# Weak convergence of an empirical process. Demonstration

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance, central-limit-theorem

The empirical process $B_n(x) = \sqrt{n}(F_n(x) − F(x))$ converges weakly to a zero-mean Gaussian process, $B$, with covariance function:

$\mbox{cov}(B(x), B(y)) = F(\min\{x, y\}) − F(x)F(y)$.

How I can prove this assumption (about covariance function)?

Comment: Do you know some basics notions of the theory of empirical processes ?

Comment: Yes, I know. Why do you ask this?

Comment: To put your question in a context. The question you ask is proved in any introductory textbook about empirical processes.

Comment: Would you recommend me an introductory textbook? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This result is called *Donsker's theorem*. It is proved in any textbook about the theory of empirical processes, such as:

- [Kosorok's book "Introduction to Empirical Processes and Semiparametric Inference"](http://books.google.be/books?id=FXaYjTQIUZ8C&dq=kosorok%20empirical&hl=fr&source=gbs_navlinks_s) (a pdf version is available [here](http://www.bios.unc.edu/~kosorok/current.pdf))
- [van der Vaart and Wellner's book "Weak Convergence and Empirical Processes"](http://books.google.be/books?id=seH8dMrEgggC&dq=kosorok%20empirical&hl=fr&source=gbs_similarbooks)

You should also easily find some courses about empirical processes with the help of Google.